How to specify an overloaded function for execution using a Hardhat Ignition Module?
I have the following module:
function createPoap(m: IgnitionModuleBuilder) {

  const proxyAdminOwner = m.getAccount(0);

  const name = m.getParameter('name');
  const symbol = m.getParameter('symbol');

  const poapContract = m.contract('Poap', [
    name,
    symbol,
    proxyAdminOwner
  ]);

  // Initialize
  const baseUri = m.getParameter('baseUri');
  m.call(poapContract, "initialize", [baseUri, []]);

  return { poapContract };
}

And I am getting this error:
Poap#Poap.initialize:
 - IGN710: Function 'initialize' is overloaded in contract Poap. Please use one of these names instead:

 - initialize()
 - initialize(string,address[])
 - initialize(address)

But when I changed it to the function I want to execute (initialize(string,address[])) I get:
IgnitionError: IGN702: Module validation failed with reason: The function name "initialize(string,address[])" is invalid, make sure you use a valid identifier.

How can I execute that function?

As @SYED-ASAD-KAZMI pointed out, there is a bug with overloaded function calls in Ignition. While he kindly suggested a temporary solution for this problem, the use of loadFixture function only works in Hardhat Network.
Looking for a more comprehensive solution that works in every network, I finally decided to completely remove Ignition modules for smart contract deployment from my project and replace it by Hardhat scripts.
This is what I ended up having:
const parameters = require("../parameters.json");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Deploy PaimaL2Contract
  const PaimaL2 = await ethers.getContractFactory("PaimaL2Contract");
  const paimaL2 = await PaimaL2.deploy(accounts[0], 1);

  await paimaL2.waitForDeployment();

  console.log("PaimaL2Contract deployed to: ", await paimaL2.getAddress());

  // Deploy Poap
  const Poap = await ethers.getContractFactory("Poap");
  const poap = await Poap.deploy(parameters.Poap.name, parameters.Poap.symbol, accounts[0].address);
  
  await poap.waitForDeployment();
  await poap["initialize(string,address[])"](parameters.Poap.baseUri, []);

  console.log("Poap deployed and initialized at: ", await poap.getAddress());
  
}

main();


This seems to be an existing problem. I've reached out to their support team and they asked me to open this issue.
Meanwhile, I was able to find an alternative solution which is by using deploy and loadFixture using module.
Here's the JS code for the same:
const { buildModule } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/modules");
const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox/network-helpers");
const { ignition } = require("hardhat");

const OverloadSumModule = buildModule("OverloadSumModule", (m) => {
  const overloadSum = m.contract("OverloadSum");
  return { overloadSum };
});

async function deployContractFixture() {

  const { overloadSum } = await ignition.deploy(OverloadSumModule);

  return { overloadSum };
}

async function interact() {

  const { overloadSum } = await loadFixture(deployContractFixture);

  let sum;

  sum = await overloadSum['sum(uint256,uint256)'](1, 2);

  console.log('Sum when calling sum(uint256,uint256):', sum);

  sum = await overloadSum['sum(uint256[])']([1, 2]);

  console.log('Sum when calling sum(uint256[]):', sum);

}

interact();

module.exports = OverloadSumModule;

In your case, the overloaded calls would be like:
await poapContract['initialize()']()

await poapContract['initialize(address)']('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

await poapContract['initialize(string,address[])']('stringArg', ['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001'])

But now, instead of running it using:
npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/YourModuleFilename.js

You've to run it using:
node ignition/modules/YourModuleFilename.js

NOTE: As, @Falcon Stakepool has mentioned in the comments, this solution seems to be working only in case of Local Hardhat Network.

Thank you so much. I have mentioned your issue in this conversation for more visibility: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-ignition/pull/31. In the meantime, I will try to implement your temporary solution. My experience with Ignition has not been the best lately: every time I have to use it is because somebody else decided to include it in their codebase and I keep finding bugs again and again.

Yeah, that’s mainly because it’s still in development phase.

You’re welcome, @FalconStakepool. Happy coding!

Hey @SYED ASAD KAZMI, I found an issue with your temporary solution: I think it doesn't work if you test outside a network that is not Hardhat Network. I am getting OnlyHardhatNetworkError: This helper can only be used with Hardhat Network. You are connected to 'localhost'. when I want to use loadFixture. More info here: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/3788

Oh okay, thanks for pointing out. Let me add that info to the answer.

Hi @SYED ASAD KAZMI, I have finally found a solution that should work in every check, in case you wanted to have a look.

Great. I'll check that out.
